# Prevent user authentication after signup with passport

Tags: node.js, express, routes, passport.js

I have set up a login/signup interface and mechanism using passport and express.js. The problem that I have is that after the signup of the user, we are redirected to the login page, but we can eventually change the URL and enter immediately in the user profile, but this is of course not expected and wanted. I would like that the user is not authenticated after the signup and that he needs to enter his/her credentials manually in the login page before entering to its profile.

```
router.get('/', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {

  res.render('library', {
    // passing the id of and username the connecting user to the dust
    userid: req.user._id,
    username: req.user.userName
  });
});

router.get('/library', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  res.render('library', {
    // passing the id of and username the connecting user to the dust
    userid: req.user._id,
    username: req.user.userName
  });
});

/* GET login page. */
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  // Display the Login page with any flash message, if any
  res.render('login', {
    message: req.flash('message')
  });
});

/* Handle Login POST 

password.authenticate is used to delegate the authentication 
to the login strategy when a HTTP POST is made to /login.
*/
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
  successRedirect: '/library',
  failureRedirect: '/',
  failureFlash: true
}));

/* GET Registration Page */
router.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
  res.render('signup', {
    message: req.flash('message')
  });
});
/* Handle Registration POST 

password.authenticate is used to delegate the authentication 
to the signup strategy when a HTTP POST is made to /signup.
*/
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
  successRedirect: '/login',
  failureRedirect: '/signup',
  failureFlash: true
}));
```

and the `isAuthenticated` function/middleware is defined as follows

```
var isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
  // if user is authenticated in the session, call the next() to call the next request handler 
  // Passport adds this method to request object. A middleware is allowed to add properties to
  // request and response objects
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Basically, after signup, I have a button which redirects to `/`, and if we are redirected to `library`  (like it's happening to me), then the user should already be authenticated, but I don't want this...

Answer (score 3):

There's at least two solutions to this:

1. Add `session: false` to the config object you pass to `passport.authenticate('signup', {...})` as described in the [passportjs documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate).
2. Don't use passport for signups. The main use case for passport is for authenticating (and establishing sessions) and DIY signup logic is more or less just a matter of copying the code from your `signup` passport middleware.

Comment: What if I set `session` to false in the object I pass to `passport.authenticate('signup', {...})` and then to true in `passport.authenticate('login', {`, what would be actual the effect?

Comment: It would probably do what you expect: signing up does not create a new session, but logging in does. Although, setting `session: true` is redundant because that is currently the default value.

Comment: But my question is then: is there any case where creating a session where signing up would be useful and secure?

Comment: It's just your preference really. One scenario where you might not want to automatically log a user in is if you are doing something like email validation, where they have to click on a special, unique link in an email you send to them before they can log in.